# How to cancel the blocking code in the coroutines

Tags: android, asynchronous, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I have the following code structure:

```
 @Throws(InterruptedException::class)
 fun method() {
     // do some blocking operations like Thread.sleep(...)
 }
 var job = launch {
     method()
 }
 job.cancelAndJoin()
```

The `method` is provided by the external library and I can't control its behaviour. It can take a lot of time for execution, so in some cases it should be canceled by timeout.

I can use the `withTimeout` function provided by the kotlin coroutines library, but it can't cancel a code with blockings due to the coroutines design. It there some workaround to do it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The main idea is to use the out of coroutines context thread pool with JVM threads that can be interrupted in the old style and subscribe to the cancellation event from the coroutine execution. When the event is caught by `invokeOnCancellation`, we can interrupt the current thread.

The implementation:

```
val externalThreadPool = Executors.newCachedThreadPool()
suspend fun <T> withTimeoutOrInterrupt(timeMillis: Long, block: () -> T) {
    withTimeout(timeMillis) {
        suspendCancellableCoroutine<Unit> { cont ->
            val future = externalThreadPool.submit {
                try {
                    block()
                    cont.resumeWith(Result.success(Unit))
                } catch (e: InterruptedException) {
                    cont.resumeWithException(CancellationException())
                } catch (e: Throwable) {
                    cont.resumeWithException(e);
                }
            }
            cont.invokeOnCancellation {
                future.cancel(true)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It provides a similar behaviour like usual `withTimeout`, but it additionally supports running a code with blockings.

Note: It should be called only when you know, that the inner code use blockings and can correctly process a thrown `InterruptedException`. In most cases, the `withTimeout` function is preferred.

**UPDATE:** Since the coroutines version 1.3.7, there has been a new function `runInterruptible`, which provides the same behaviour. So this code can be simplified:

```
suspend fun <T> withTimeoutOrInterrupt(timeMillis: Long, block: () -> T) {
    withTimeout(timeMillis) {
        runInterruptible(Dispatchers.IO) {
            block()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Isn't there a shorter version of this? Even AsyncTask is shorter...

Comment: @androiddeveloper, I have added an example with a new function `runInterruptible`.

Comment: I see. Say, about runInterruptible, what if I want to store some field for it? Using AsyncTask, we could extend from it. Now we need to wrap what we get from it?

Comment: And also how can I handle cancellation back on the UI thread?

Comment: @VictorKhovanskiy does `runIterruptible` provide access to `Continuation` in order to perform some cleanup maybe?